# X is not a function - How to fix

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating TS3 Query Bot using [this](https://github.com/Multivit4min/TS3-NodeJS-Library)

I came up with core.js, register.js and 2 configs for them that are not important in here.

Core.js:

```
const TeamSpeak3 = require("ts3-nodejs-library")
var config = require("./configs/config.js")

//Create a new Connection
const ts3 = new TeamSpeak3({
    host: "localhost",
    queryport: 10011,
    serverport: 9987,
    username: "serveradmin",
    password: "",
    nickname: "NodeJS Query Framework"
})

/*
  Ready gets fired when the Bot has connected to the TeamSpeak Query and
  issued login commands (if username and password has been given)
  selected the appropriate Server (also if given in the config)
  and set the nickname
*/
ts3.on("ready", async () => {
    Promise.all([
        ts3.registerEvent("server"),
        ts3.registerEvent("channel", 0),
        ts3.registerEvent("textserver"),
        ts3.registerEvent("textchannel"),
        ts3.registerEvent("textprivate")
    ]).then(() => {
        console.log("[ JANbot ] Nasluchuje eventow: server, channel (0), textserver, textchannel, textprivate")
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log("Catched an error!")
        console.error(e)
    })
})

if(config.registerEnabled = true) {
    var register = require("./inc/functions/register.js")
    ts3.on("clientmoved", event => {
            register.registerUser(event, event.client)
    })
}

ts3.on("error", e => console.log("Error", e.message))
ts3.on("close", e => console.log("Connection has been closed!", e))
```

register.js:

```
module.exports = function() {
    this.registerUser = function(event, client) 
    {
        var register_config = require("/home/node_modules/bot/configs/register_config.js")
        if(event.channel.cid == register_config.channelId) {
            if(! client.servergroups.includes(register_config.groupId)) {
                event.client.addGroups(config.groupId)
                event.client.message("You have been successfully registered!")
                event.client.kickFromChannel()
                return console.log("zarejestrowano " + event.client.nickname)
            } else {
                event.client.message("You are already registred!")
                event.client.kickFromChannel()
                return console.log(event.client.nickname + " juz jest zarejestrowany")
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Main idea is to handle bot and its connection in core.js and just require specific functions to it to make easier updates (you don't need to download whole core.js with many functions, just one file and eventually a config for it)

The error i am getting:

```
Error register.registerUser is not a function
```

I'm not advanced in JS so please if I did anything wrong except my problem please tell me that. I have some little thoughts what's wrong but I cannot fix that. I think that registerUser is not function but I don't have any idea how to implement register.js into here:

```
if(config.registerEnabled = true) {
    var register = require("./inc/functions/register.js")
    ts3.on("clientmoved", event => {
            register.registerUser(event, event.client)
    })
}
```

Btw. I added returns only because I thought it would change registerUser into function.`1`

//EDIT:
It works, but now I struggle with second problem.
Now the code:

```
module.exports = {
    registerUser: function(event, client) 
    {
        var register_config = require("/home/node_modules/bot/configs/register_config.js")
        if(event.channel.cid == register_config.channelId) {
            var grupa = register_config.groupId
            if(!event.client.servergroups.includes(register_config.groupId)) {
                var date = new Date(),
                    g = date.getHours(),
                    m = date.getMinutes(),
                    s = date.getSeconds()
                event.client.addGroups(register_config.groupId)
                event.client.poke("You have been successfully registered!")
                event.client.kickFromChannel()
                console.log(" [ " + g + " : " + m + " : " + s + " ] " +'Zarejestronwalem: ' + client.nickname)
            } else {
                event.client.poke("You are already registered!")
                event.client.kickFromChannel()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the part:

> if(!event.client.servergroups.includes(register_config.groupId)) {

is always true because somehow array servergroups of client doesn't have the number 11 in it so script just thinks it's true. I added console.log(event.client.servergroups) to see if is it problem of register_config.groupId or something else and this shows up in console:

> [ 9, 11 ]

So after that I have spotted that it is problem with register_config.groupId because bot with code like this:
(core.js is the same as it was before second problem appeard)

register.js:

```
module.exports = {
    registerUser: function(event, client) 
    {
        var register_config = require("/home/node_modules/bot/configs/register_config.js")
        if(event.channel.cid == register_config.channelId) {
            var grupa = register_config.groupId
            if(!event.client.servergroups.includes(register_config.groupId)) {
                var date = new Date(),
                    g = date.getHours(),
                    m = date.getMinutes(),
                    s = date.getSeconds()
                event.client.addGroups(register_config.groupId)
                event.client.poke("You have been successfully registered!")
                event.client.kickFromChannel()
                console.log(" [ " + g + " : " + m + " : " + s + " ] " +'Zarejestronwalem: ' + client.nickname)
            } else {
                event.client.poke("You are already registered!")
                event.client.kickFromChannel()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

register_config.js:

```
module.exports = {
        channelId: 4,
        groupdId: 11
}
```

Bot behaves like here:

> client on random channel (not with cid 4)
>   client joins channel with cid 4
>   bot kicks him,
>       pokes him,
>       doesn't give him server group

Conclusion: register_config.groupId somehow isn't defined as number eleven.

//EDIT #2:

I've done this:

```
var register_config = {

        "groupId": 11,
        "channelId": 4

};

module.exports = register_config;
```

And it works :) Never mind and thank you for help !

Comment: You are exporting a function so register would be a function.

Comment: But error appears @epascarello

Comment: because `register` is a function, I would expect it to be an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *register.js* export an object instead of a function:

```
// module.exports = function() {
module.exports = {
    // this.registerUser = function(event, client) 
    registerUser: function(event, client) 
    {
        var register_config = require("/home/node_modules/bot/configs/register_config.js")
        if(event.channel.cid == register_config.channelId) {
            if(! client.servergroups.includes(register_config.groupId)) {
                event.client.addGroups(config.groupId)
                event.client.message("You have been successfully registered!")
                event.client.kickFromChannel()
                return console.log("zarejestrowano " + event.client.nickname)
            } else {
                event.client.message("You are already registred!")
                event.client.kickFromChannel()
                return console.log(event.client.nickname + " juz jest zarejestrowany")
            }
        }
    };
}
```